# MySQL procedure to insert and delete

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create an MySQL procedure to insert in a table and remove in an other table...

My procedure :

```
insert ignore into old_events (select * from events where start < now());
delete from events where start < now();
```

Error message : `insert ignore into old_events (select * from events where start < now());
delete from events where start < now();`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `()` when using [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

```
insert ignore into old_events 
select * 
from `events` 
where `start` < now();
```

Consider using column list instead of `*`:

```
insert ignore into old_events(col1, col2, ...) 
select col1, col2, ... 
from `events` 
where `start` < now();
```

Keep in mind that `now()` is time-dependent and you should store its result in variable for comparing. Between `INSERT` and `DELETE` `now()` could change.

Comment: And what about `DELETE`?

Answer (score 0):

As i saw you insert query you insert data into old_events column but you select all column from the events table. so you can select only that column which you want to insert into old_events column

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO old_events 
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE start < now();

DELETE FROM events WHERE start < now();
```

In my System i have created two table

```
create table events( id int,event_name varchar(20), start timestamp default current_timestamp);
create table old_events( id int,event_name varchar(20), start timestamp default current_timestamp);
```

and then 6 rows inserted into `events` table

```
insert into events(id,event_name, start) values 
(1,'event1','2016-02-18'),
(2,'event2','2016-02-19'),
(3,'event3','2016-02-20'),
(4,'event4','2016-02-21'),
(5,'event5','2016-02-22'),
(6,'event6','2016-02-23');
```

and i execute select query where start is less than `current time`

```
SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE start < now();
```

**its return 5 rows** [see example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36bbb/6)

but in sqlfiddle, we can run only select query so after this execute  below query in my system and it successfully execute and 5 rows inserted into old_events where start is less than `current time`

```
INSERT INTO old_events
SELECT * 
FROM EVENTS WHERE START < NOW();
```

after than i select rows from old_events table its return 5 rows

```
select * from old_events;
```

after than i execute delete query and its delete 5 rows from events table

```
DELETE FROM EVENTS WHERE START < NOW();
```

after all step i execute two more query select from `events and old_events table`

```
select * from events;  // its return 1 row where start is greater than now()
select * from old_events; // its return 5 row where start is less than now()
```

Comment: It doesn't work, my old events are deleted in `events` but no insertion in `old_events`...

Comment: what is the structure of both table can you provide data type of both

Comment: It's the same structure and they have the same data types... The error message `#1054 - Unknown column 'old_events' in 'field list'`.

Comment: can you provide structure of both table?

Comment: according to your error `old_events` column does not exist in events tales.  so i can give right query

Comment: When I execute the SQL query in the textarea in `phpMyAdmin` it works... But when I create a procedure with this SQL query I get the error message `MySQL #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM events WHERE start < NOW()' at line 2`...

Comment: add procedure defination in query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104264/discussion-between-vipin-jain-and-tonymx227).